# JavaScript OOP and setInterval help needed

Tags: javascript, oop, timer

I am programming a web page, which will a different message every 4 seconds.  I have built a custom object which I intend to pull information from to create the strings to be displayed.  I'm using a function similar to Math.random called 'rand' which will let me access the object randomly.  I've set the interval for 4 seconds.  I can get the string to be displayed, but after that the web page continues to load and load and begins to lag so badly that I have to exit out.  The code I'm using is shown below.  Please help!

```
  var name = "Barack Obama";

  var Actions = {

    "ActionList" : [

        { "action" : "watches a 30 minute TV show",
          "time"   : 30,
          "time_measure" : "minute",
          "assuming" : "assuming he sat through the commercials too"
         },

        {
          "action" : "makes some pizza rolls",
          "time" : 9,
          "time_measure" : "minute",
          "assuming" : "he only made one plateful"
         },

        {
          "action" : "takes a 2 hour nap",
          "time" : 2,
          "time_measure" : "hour",
          "assuming" : "assuming he's a heavy sleeper"
         },

        {
          "action" : "1000 jumping jacks",
          "time" : 1,
          "time_measure" : "hour",
          "assuming" : "he doesn't take a break, or slow down"
         }
    ]

  };

  function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  function run() {

    /**
     * RANDOMLY SELECT OBJECTS
    ***/
    var r = rand(0, 3);

    var x = Actions.ActionList[r]["action"];

    document.write( x );

  }



  setInterval(run, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aHrpC/2/

This JSFiddle has a working example.  It had to do with document.write.  Everything else in your code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use document.write after the page is loaded. It destroys the current page.

You should be using DOM methods like appendChild() or innerHTML.

Comment: took your advice, but after editing the code I don't get any output from the code.